# How do I resolve this list index out of range error while reading text file in python?

Tags: python, index-error

This is my code:

```
fp = open("todo.txt", "r")

todoContent = fp.readlines()[1:]

for each in todoContent:
    items = each.split(",")
    print("{:} : {:} {:} important and {:} urgent, it {:} been completed".format(
        todoContent.index(each) +1, items[0],
        "is" if items[1] == "Yes" else "is not",
        "is" if items[2] == "Yes" else "is not",
        "has" if items[3] == "Yes" else "has not"))

fp.close()
```

Here is the output:

```
1 : AB0403 Assignment is important and is not urgent, it has not been completed
2 : Watch Star Wars is not important and is not urgent, it has not been completed
3 : LAMS 4 is important and is urgent, it has not been completed
4 : Buy Grocery is not important and is urgent, it has not been completed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/au_yi/PycharmProjects/Python Class AB0403/For testing.py", line 10, in <module>
    "is" if items[1] == "Yes" else "is not",
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I've tried several methods but I cant seem to get rid of the error. I would like to keep the output the way it is and only remove the error so it looks like this:

```
1 : AB0403 Assignment is important and is not urgent, it has not been completed
2 : Watch Star Wars is not important and is not urgent, it has not been completed
3 : LAMS 4 is important and is urgent, it has not been completed
4 : Buy Grocery is not important and is urgent, it has not been completed
```

Here is the txt file:

```
Name,Important,Urgent,Complete
AB0403 Assignment,Yes,No,No
Watch Star Wars,No,No,No
LAMS 4,Yes,Yes,Yes
Buy Grocery,No,Yes,No
```

Comment: You have an end of line at the end of the file.

Comment: You have an empty line in the file.